# Python Django: How to pass in variable with 'url' call inside of template

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to pass in a variable for this url function defined in my urls.py:

```
path("edit/<str:title>", views.edit, name="edit"),
```

From my html template, I did this:

```
<a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit/{{ entry }}' %}">Edit Entry</a>
```

The goal of this is so the user can click this hyperlink to edit some text within in a textarea box. For that I wanted to pass in the specific name of the page, e.g. HTML. That is what the "entry" variable is used for. However, because of this little bit of code `'encyclopedia:edit/{{ entry }}'` I get an error:

Here is the error:

> Reverse for 'edit/{{ entry }}' not found. 'edit/{{ entry }}' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I am fairly new to Django, but I know that I am using Django syntax incorrectly in this case. Usually I would be able to do this with a simple

```
<a href="edit/{{ entry }}">Edit Entry</a>
```

But will this pass in "entry" as a variable?
How would I insert "entry" in this snippet of code `'encyclopedia:edit/{{ entry }}'`?

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit' entry %}">Edit Entry</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it will for sure

```
<a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit' title=entry %}">Edit Entry</a>
```